How can I enable and use SPI on the Lichee pi zero dock when using the Debian LXDE image provided by the company?
I am using the Lichee Pi Zero Dock with the official Debian LXDE image provided by the company. I need to use SPI for my project, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. I’ve tried looking for the correct drivers or configurations but haven't been able to find a solution. Could someone guide me through enabling SPI on the LicheePi Zero Dock, including any necessary configuration or driver setup? Specifically, how do I check if SPI is enabled, and what steps are needed to activate it if it isn't?
I have connected an RC522 RFID module to the SPI pins, and I want to read the UID of RFID cards. However, I'm having trouble getting SPI to work and communicating with the RC522 module.
I’m not sure if SPI is enabled or properly configured on the LicheePi Zero. I’ve tried basic troubleshooting, but I still can’t get any readings from the RFID module. Could someone guide me through the steps to enable and configure SPI, and provide any necessary commands or libraries that will help me communicate with the RC522 module?
